# Select absolute last element

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to select the absolute last element with a class. This can be nested inside a lot of elements, it can be its own element somewhere on the page, it can literally be anywhere. Here's what I've tried:

https://jsfiddle.net/cztpog87/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="total">
        Money!
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="total">
            Money!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="total">
        Money!
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="total">
        Money!
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="total">
            Money!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="total">
        Money!
    </div>
    <div class="total">
        Money!
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.total:not(:last-of-type) {
    display: none;
}

.total:not(:last-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

As you can see, it doesn't remove ALL the elements. It removes some but definitely not all. What is the absolute best way to remove ALL but the last? SASS is also welcome.

Comment: Not possible with CSS. You need Javascript. There is no `nth-of-class` CSS Selector.

Comment: @Paulie_D What a shame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply this is not possible with CSS as there is no `nth-of-class` selector

With Jquery it's simplicity itself with the `.last` function.

```js
$(".total").last().addClass("highlight");
```

```css
.total.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="total">
    Money!
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="total">
      Money!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="total">
    Money!
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="total">
    Money!
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="total">
      Money!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="total">
    Money!
  </div>
  <div class="total">
    Money!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it isn't possible with pure CSS, so you need a little JavaScript.

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.total');

if (elems.length) {
  elems[elems.length - 1].className += ' total-last'
}
```

```css
.total {
  background: yellow;
}

.total-last {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="total">
        Money!
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="total">
            Money!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="total">
        Money!
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="total">
        Money!
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="total">
            Money!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="total">
        Money!
    </div>
    <div class="total">
        Money!
    </div>
</div>
```

*Don't forget to put your script after your HTML elements, or execute it after DOMReady.*